# SharePoint 2013: what is the use of "customstrings.js"

Tags: 2013, javascript, content-search-web-part, sharepoint-server

I have a Content Search web part with a dynamic query on a SharePoint page in our site.

When I added this web part it was throwing below error:

> One or more of the following resource files failed to load: /_catalogs/masterpage/display templates/language files/en-US/customstrings.js?ctag=1945$$15.0.5047.1000.

To resolve this error, I downloaded `customstrings.js` file from another site and added it on the current site manually by creating a folder `en-US` under `language files` folder.

Sometimes it works as expected. But, when more than 15-20 users hits this page simultaneously it throws same error as above.

Does anyone know how to resolve this error and what is the use `customstrings.js` file in content serach web part?

Comment: Anyone knows how to solve this error?